# Replace crystal earpiece in bat detector circuit

Tags: design, impedance

I've been following the instructions on http://pw1.netcom.com/~t-rex/BatDetector.html which includes the following schematic for a Frequency Division Bat Detector circuit:

[image: Bat Detector schematic]

The instructions clearly state (http://home.earthlink.net/~bat-detector/SBD2Parts.html note #5) that a crystal earpiece should be used. However these are increasingly hard to come by.

Is it possible to use a non-crystal earphone with this circuit? Or is there any recommended modification to the circuit to enable it to drive a pair of earphones?

Comment: Easiest would probably with a transformer, but you can surely build some high impedance input amp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The crystal earpiece has such high impedence that it presents virtually no load to the CD4024. Normal earphones have impedence in the 16 to 32 ohm range, which would (at 9V) cause the CD4024 to provide far more current than it's capable of, potentially damaging or killing it.

You need an amplifier with high input impedence which is capable of driving headphones. The LM386 you're using already in your circuit would work. The [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm386.pdf) gives an application circuit for an amplifier connected to a speaker. You've already got the 10k volume selector.

Comment: Yes, I was just musing this. I will experiment with re-arranging the amplifiers and see if that works better.

Comment: Further digging gets me to this page, which recommends exactly the suggested advice. Accepted answer! bertrik.sikken.nl/bat/my_div.htm